# Rails 3: Why am I not able to see the input fields that should be generated by form_for?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, debugging

[What I see](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JspWT.png)

The following is my Track template:

app/views/tracks/index.html.erb

```
<h1>Playlist</h1>

<%= form_for @track do |f| %>
    <%= f.error_messages %>
    <p>
        <%= f.text_field :youtube_url %>
        <%= f.submit 'Add' %>
    </p>
<% end %>

<hr />

<% if Track.first == nil %>
<p>Database is empty!</p>
<%else%>
<% @tracks.each do |track| %>
  <ul>
    <li><%= track.youtube_url %></li>
  </ul>
<% end %>
<% end %>
```

And clearly, the input fields are not being shown for some reason.

The other relevant files: 
app/controllers/tracks_controllers.rb

```
class TracksController < ApplicationController
def index
    @track = Track.new
    @tracks = Track.all
end

def create 
    @track = Track.new(params[:track])
    render :action=>"index"

end

def delete
    @track = Track.find(params[:id])
    @track.destroy

    redirect_to(tracks_url)
end
end
```

routes.rb

```
Music::Application.routes.draw do
   resources :tracks
end
```

track.rb
    class Track < ActiveRecord::Base
      attr_accessible :title, :youtube_url
    end

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: You don't set `@track` variable in this action. Yet it still doesn't explain what happens.

Comment: I just attempted it @ErminDedovic, nothing changes.

Comment: @Louis93 Can you check my answer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to put `<%=` opening tag in your `form_for` instead of `<%`.

```
<%= form_for @track do |f| %>
    <%= f.error_messages %>
    <p>
        <%= f.text_field :youtube_url %>
        <%= f.submit 'Add' %>
    </p>
<% end %>
```

Comment: Excellent, that does fix the problem of the input elements not showing up, thank you. But I am unable to add new elements, and I receive this: `undefined method `save' for nil:NilClass`, do you have any insight into this?

Comment: What does your Track model contain?

Comment: Nothing except for youtube_url and title member variables. I've added it in the above description never the less. I seem to have solved the problem through a workaround, however, the database looks like it's always empty even after I input information into it?

Comment: And thank you for the support, this is my first RoR app I'm trying to develop.

Comment: You didn't save the model. You need @track.save in your create action.

Comment: There were a couple of things afterwards but I figured it out. Thanks!